# CSS validation not validating

Tags: validation, css, w3c-validation

```
/* ** ** custom select color ** ** */
::selection {
 background: #525252; /* Safari */
}
::-moz-selection {
 background: #525252; /* Firefox */
 color:#fff;
}
```

The above code is not passing the W3C validator, but I can't understand the reason for it.

The following error is returned:

> The pseudo-element ::selection can't
> appear here in the context css21
> [selection]
>
> The pseudo-element
> ::-moz-selection can't appear here in
> the context css21 [-moz-selection]

Comment: Usually they give you a reason. It could possibly be the -moz prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1        The pseudo-element ::selection can't appear here in the context css21 [selection]
4        The pseudo-element ::-moz-selection can't appear here in the context css21 [-moz-selection]
```

That's nothing to worry about, the first one is complaining because it's being tested against CSS2.1, and the second, as Kyle suggested, is because of the -moz prefix

To silence the first "error", do the following:

[image]

Click on the more options link and change the profile to CSS 3.

This can not silence the second error, and should probably learn to ignore this kind of errors. I know it sounds a big of a pain, unless anyone can offer an alternative suggestion?

Comment: how can i silent it, so i know what parts to look for in the css and not check every time. with big css files it gets problematic.

Comment: Also, `::selection` has been removed from Selectors level 3: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selection

Comment: In a future version of the validator it is likely that there will be a mode to ignore the -vendor- prefixes.

Comment: @karlcow There's a mode to have the vendor prefixes register as warning rather than errors, you can see the drop down in the screenshot above

Comment: ah yep already fixed. :) I must have been sleeping during the commits.

Answer (score 0):

```
::-moz-selection
```

Mozilla/Webkit specific CSS elements do not validate even under CSS level 3.

Answer (score 0):

Today you have a problem even with ::selection because it was dropped from CSS3.